# Get all posts from Workflow in Channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a Slack channel at my workplace where every new member is prompted via workflow to enter some information, and then the workflow posts it to the channel (there is a **Workflow** tag next to it). I want to organize all of the responses to that workflow in a single space, either by exporting it from Slack or by consolidating into a single post.

I believe I could use the `workflow_published` event object to catch them moving forward (in fact, I could even just add an additional step to the existing workflow I believe), but how could I go back and scrape previous responses to this workflow?

Apologies, I do not have any pre-existing code as I need to request access through our security team, which is pretty strict, and I want to know what is the least amount of permissions I can request.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can use the [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) api to fetch all the messages from then channel and then extract information by applying required filters (e.g. subtype, username, bot_id).